# Input text greys out on mobile ( not on desktop) with disabled property

Tags: javascript, css

I have an input text that for functionality reasons, everytime a click is made on a button, I have to add the property `disabled` with the aid of javascript, such as the following:

`<input class="input" value="1" readonly="" name="input-id-1234" disabled="" hidden="true">`

This property is causing the text/value on the input to go grey on mobile.

```css
    input {
      border: none;
      text-align: center;
      width: 20px;
    }
    input:disabled {
      -webkit-appearance: none !important;
      opacity: 2 !important;
      color: black !important;
    }
    input:focus {
      outline: none;
    }
```

```html
<div>
<input class="input" value="1" readonly="" name="input-id-1234" disabled="true">
</div>
```

This was supposed to work but it is not working on mobile.

Any ideas on how to override the browser `disabled` property color ( grey out) ?

Answer (score 0):

Ended up fixing it, fix was the following:

```
.input {
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  color: black !important;
  &:disabled {
    color: black;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: currentColor;
  }
}
.input:disabled {
  -webkit-appearance: none !important;
  opacity: 1 !important;
  color: black !important;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: black !important;
}
input {
  border: none;
  text-align: center;
  width: 20px;
  color: black;
}
input:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to update the background color or text color of a disabled input with your "input" class name, you can simply use the following

```
.input:disabled {
  color: black; // Text color
  background-color: red; // Background color
}
```

If you want to change the text color of the disabled input *placeholder* text, you can use

```
.input:disabled::placeholder {
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: it's not the background color I want to update but the text color of the input. I have used `input` to style as an example, it could have been `.input` instead.

Comment: I believe you are trying to change the style of the placeholder text, which you should use ` input:disabled::placeholder { color: red } ` to change that

Comment: no, I am trying to change the `input innerHTML` which is in fact the input value, not the placeholder. have updated my question with a snippet instead

Comment: You can simply use the `color: red` style on the disabled input selector (or whichever color you'd like). You currently have `color: black !important;`, which makes the text input color black. If you want to change the disabled input background color, use the `background-color` style in my first snippet. There is no need to mess with innerHTML here.

Comment: I think you are confused by my question. I don't want to change the background, I want to change the input value color. If you look at my snippet and run it you will see the number 1 in there. That is the text color I want to be black. As you can see, on desktop you see black,but not on mobile atm, it greys out on mobile

Comment: If you run your snippet with a mobile device, the text color for the "1" is black. You may have a conflicting style going on.

Comment: I have tried, it is grey